# List and load files in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps, shiny-reactivity

I'm new to Shiny and i'm really stuck! I'm trying to build an app where users can select a file from a list of files in a folder and simply load and display it. I've looked at similar questions but I really can't understand why my code does not work. I don't get any error msg, the output panel just stays blank..

Any help much appreciated thank you

Best Regards

```
library(shiny)
fpath <- "/dbfs/May2022"
ui <-   fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(
selectInput('selectfile','Select File',choice = list.files(fpath)),
textOutput('fileselected'),
  mainPanel("Main Panel",dataTableOutput("txtout"),style = "font-size:100%") # mainPanel
)

server <- function(input,output)
{reactive({
  fullpath <- file.path(fpath,input$selectfile)
  req(fullpath)
    df <- read.csv(fullpath, header = TRUE,  sep = ",")})
  output$fileselected <- renderText({
    paste0('You have selected: ', input$selectfile)
  })
 req(df)
  output$txtout <- renderDataTable(
          head(df), options =list(pageLength = 5))
  }

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: I see a few small missing items, a parenthesis to end the UI, and moving the starting bracket from the server up to the server line can help prevent errors. But as you said you aren't seeing errors, then these probably aren't the issues you are encountering. To clarify the issue, are you able to see the files in ```input$selectfile``` and select the files? Just not display them in the ```output$txtout```?

Comment: Hi, Yes I can see the files and print the one that gets selected.. it's almost like the file is not importing when selected.. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I think below should work:

```
library(shiny)
fpath <- "/dbfs/May2022"
ui <-   fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput('selectfile','Select File',choice = list.files(fpath)),
    textOutput('fileselected'),
    mainPanel("Main Panel",dataTableOutput("txtout"),style = "font-size:100%") # mainPanel
  )
)#Added a missing parenthesis
  
  server <- function(input,output, session) {#I added session, just because I always see it there, don't really know if it's needed
    # Also, I moved the brackets from around reactive to up to the server
    output$fileselected<-renderText({
      paste0('You have selected: ', input$selectfile)
    })
    
  # reactive({#I was told it's not a good idea to put outputs within reactives, so I blocked this out
    # fullpath <- file.path(fpath,input$selectfile)
    # req(fullpath)
    # df <- read.csv(fullpath, header = TRUE,  sep = ",")})
    # output$fileselected <- renderText({
    #   paste0('You have selected: ', input$selectfile)
    # })
    # req(df)
    output$txtout <- renderDataTable({
      req(input$selectfile)
      fullpath <- file.path(fpath,input$selectfile)
      df <- read.csv(fullpath, header = TRUE,  sep = ",")
      head(df)
      }, options =list(pageLength = 5))
  }
  
  shinyApp(ui,server)
```

I put some comments in the code itself where I added a parenthesis and moved a bracket. The biggest thing I did though was just get rid of the `reactive`. I used one output for the `input$fileselected`, to state which file is chosen, and then the second one, `output$txtout` is where the data is read in and displayed. Hopefully this helps and makes sense!

Comment: Manu thanks I will try first thing tomorrow morning as it's very late here, a big thank you for your help